# CSS element layout problems

Tags: css, css-position, positioning

I'm new to CSS layouts and have hit a problem.
This is what I currently have. http://jsfiddle.net/EPp5C/5/

```
#login {   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
}
#login ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}   
#login ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:14px;
    color: white;
}
```

There are 2 parts to this question.
First part:

I would like the list items to be displayed as

> Username:   Password:
>
> [textfield] [texfield]

so have the textfields under the corissponding username and password.

Comment: what have you tried? what have you read? a quick google search turns up Tons of great resources on the topic - i would recommend looking into understanding the foundations of css focusing on how the 'display', 'position', 'float' and 'clear' attributes work

Comment: Oh sorry, the second part wasn't submitted. The second part was to push  it about 60px inside the blue area. I would have thought that because it was nested inside the nav_main div tag, it would automatically be inside there

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/EPp5C/6/

I added a `<br>` with a class of clear.  I then gave this class the attributes of `clear:both;`.  This will push the floats onto a new line.  If you want to line them up, add a width to the elements.  If you want to move them further up the page, add a margin-top to the parent elements.

```
    <ul>
        <li>Username: </li>
        <li>Password: </li>
        <br class="clear" />
        <li><input type="text" name="username" /></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="password" /></li>
    </ul>


.clear { clear:both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your `html`.

You do not need to put this form info in a `ul`.  In fact, that would be semantically incorrect.

Here is what I suggest:

**HTML**

```
<div id="login">
    <form>
        <label>Username:</label><label>Password:</label> 
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <input type="text" name="password" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:170px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Also, to put it inside the colored `div` as much as possible, I used `margin-top` on the `#login`

```
#login {   
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
    **margin-top:-30px;**
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/EPp5C/9/

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to put the form child inside span tag
working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ4nJ/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="login">
  <form>
    <span>Username:<input type="text" name="username" /></span>&nbsp
    <span>Password:<input type="text" name="password" /></span>  
  </form>
</div>
```

[reference:](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)The **<span>** tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

**CSS** (refer complete CSS at the fiddle)

```
span{
  margin-right:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  width:220px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

hope it can help